# Docker Setup - Networking between multiple containers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, docker-machine, confluent-platform

On my linux server, I am running 3 images -

A) Docker and Zookeeper with this docker-compose file -

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    expose:
     - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

This will open up the kafka broker to the host machine.

B) JupyterHub

```
docker run -v /notebooks:/notebooks -p 8000:8000 jupyterhub
```

C) Confluent Schema Registry (I have not tried it yet, but in my final setup I will have a schema registry container as well)

```
docker run confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
```

Both are starting up without any issues. But how do I open up jupyterhub container to kafka container and schema registry ports so that my python scripts can access the brokers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to run your jupyter notebook container on demand whereas your zookeeper and kafka containers will always be running separately? You can create a [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and join all the containers to this network. Then your containers will be able resolve each other by their names.

1. [Create a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)
2. [Specify this network in compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks)
3. When starting your other containers with `docker run`, use [`--network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) option.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `docker network ls` then you can find the name of the network that [Compose creates for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/); it will be named something like `directoryname_default`.  You can then launch the containers connected to that network,

```
docker run --net directoryname_default confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
```

If you can include these files in the same `docker-compose.yml` file then you won’t need to do anything special.  In particular this probably makes sense for the Confluent schema registry, which you can consider a core part of the Kafka stack if you’re using Avro messages.

You can use the Docker Compose service name `kafka` as a host name here, but since you need to connect to the “inside” listener you’ll need to configure a non-default port 9093.  (The Docker Compose `expose:` directive doesn’t do much and you can safely delete it.)